# Unable to add/connect CosmosDB in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-analysis-services

I have created an Azure Analysis Service and CosmosDB in same region (West-India).But when I try to add new Model in Azure Analysis Service, I able to find only Sample Data(Adventurous DW) in the data source list. I am unable to find CosmosDB name in the drop down list of data sources.

Microsoft has mentioned that we can connect to Cosmos DB from Azure analysis Services for In-memory model. But I can't even find Cosmos DB in the list.[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource

Comment: Great! Si if you think my answer helps you, could you mark it for answer?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed the official tutorial:[Add a sample model from the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-create-sample-model),you could only work with sample model which is a completed version of the `Adventure Works Internet Sales (1200)` sample data model. A sample model is useful for testing model management, connecting with tools and client applications, and querying model data.

But based on the statements in the [supported list data source document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource),the cosmos db needs `Tabular 1400 and higher models` only.

[image]

So,please follow the [Adventure Works tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/analysis-services/tutorials/aas-adventure-works-tutorial) to [create a tabular model project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/analysis-services/tutorials/aas-lesson-1-create-a-new-tabular-model-project).Then you could [create a connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/analysis-services/tutorials/aas-lesson-2-get-data) to your cosmos db account inn Tabular Model Explorer, right-click `Data Sources > Import from Data Source`.

[image]

Key your db infomation:

[image]

Also,you could refer to a case related to this:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9394a10b-f085-4a68-9951-5000a6f799ef/cosmos-db-data-source-how-to-configure-the-key-in-azure-analysis-services?forum=AzureAnalysisServices

Comment: Now I got it , I have to import CosmosDB data into my Analysis Project then make a model and then deploy that model in azure analysis services. Sucessfully deployed model will present in the dropdown list along with Sample Adeventure Works model. I misunderstood sample Adventure Works DW model as data source , hence expecting CosmosDB in the drop down list